# PDE headless build issues with eclipse RCP migration from 3.7.2 to 4.3.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

We are in the process of migrating our application from 3.7.2 to 4.3.2, but facing few issues during pde-build. Though I can get the application to build and launch and work well from the Eclipse 4.3.2 IDE itself, the command line build fails with messages about many missing plugins, compile failures etc.

In the log file there are lots of missing plugin messages, but the Eclipse 4.3.2 folder I am providing for the pde build has all these missing jars in it's plugins folder. I have confirmed this by searching for the actual jar names in the Eclipse SDK directory unzipped by the build for its later consumption.

These are the messages from the log after the pde-build target is run:

```
[eclipse.generateFeature] Some inter-plug-in dependencies have not been satisfied.
[eclipse.generateFeature] Bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core.nl1:
[eclipse.generateFeature]   Host plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.core_[5.5.0,5.6.0) has not been found.
[eclipse.generateFeature] Bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core.nl2a:
[eclipse.generateFeature]   Host plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.core_[5.5.0,5.6.0) has not been found.
[eclipse.generateFeature] Bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core.nl2:
[eclipse.generateFeature]   Host plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.core_[5.5.0,5.6.0) has not been found.
[eclipse.generateFeature] Bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core.nlBidi:
[eclipse.generateFeature]   Host plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.core_[5.5.0,5.6.0) has not been found.
[eclipse.generateFeature] Bundle org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.nl1:
[eclipse.generateFeature]   Host plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core_[7.3.0,7.4.0) has not been found.
[eclipse.generateFeature] Bundle org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.nl2a:
[eclipse.generateFeature]   Host plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core_[7.3.0,7.4.0) has not been found.
[eclipse.generateFeature] Bundle org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.nl2:
[eclipse.generateFeature]   Host plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core_[7.3.0,7.4.0) has not been found.
```

I also get errors related to compile failures after all those missing plugin messages:

```
[83 units compiled]
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 1. ERROR in C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\toolkit\plugins\com.app.ecm.configmgr.engine\src\com\app\ecm\configmgr\engine\util\XmlDoc.java (at line 0)
    [javac]     /* app Confidential
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] ***The type java.lang.Class cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files***
    *[javac] ----------
    [javac] 1 problem (1 error)
    [javac] Compilation failed. Compiler errors are available in C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\toolkit\plugins\com.app.ecm.configmgr.engine/@dot.log
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Administrator\chechand_Common_3PT_3\vobs\fnet_3pt\eclipse\4.3.2\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml:43: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Administrator\chechand_Common_3PT_3\vobs\fnet_3pt\Eclipse\4.3.2\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\scripts\build.xml:105: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Administrator\chechand_Common_3PT_3\vobs\fnet_3pt\Eclipse\4.3.2\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\templates\headless-build\customTargets.xml:12: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Administrator\chechand_Common_3PT_3\vobs\fnet_3pt\Eclipse\4.3.2\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\scripts\productBuild\allElements.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Administrator\chechand_Common_3PT_3\vobs\fnet_3pt\Eclipse\4.3.2\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\scripts\genericTargets.xml:118: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Administrator\chechand_Common_3PT_3\vobs\fnet_3pt\Eclipse\4.3.2\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\scripts\genericTargets.xml:123: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\toolkit\features\org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature\build.xml:30: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\toolkit\features\org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature\build.xml:16: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\toolkit\features\com.app.ecm.configmgr.ui.feature\build.xml:63: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\toolkit\features\com.app.ecm.configmgr.ui.feature\build.xml:19: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\toolkit\plugins\com.app.ecm.configmgr.engine\build.xml:329: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\vobs\chechand_CM_cm521\vobs\build\toolkit\plugins\com.app.ecm.configmgr.engine\build.xml:290: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I have searched through the forum but didn't find anything related to issues I am facing.

Edit: I have added Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment= JavaSE-1.7 in my MANIFEST.MF for my product but I still face this issue.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: It may be plugin versions that are the problem, for example `org.eclipse.cdt.core.nl1` wants a version of `org.eclipse.cdt.core` which is at least 5.5.0 but less than 5.6.0 - is that what you have?

Comment: Hello Greg, 
Thanks for the reply, I went back and checked my plugin versions and here is what I found for the first 2 missing plugins in the error log above: 

org.eclipse.cdt.core_5.6.0.201402142303.jar.
org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core_7.4.0.201402142303.jar

Comment: Looks like the nlxx plugins may be from an older version (they aren't part of the normal CDT download). I think these are just message language translations so you could leave them out.